# Mongodb - remove or replace all array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How can i replace all elements from a mongodb array element.  As in below example, my requirement is to remove both object from skills array and add new elements in it.

```
{
    "_id": "uniqueid",
    "skills": [
        { "skill": "dancer" },
        { "skill": "singer" }
    ]
}
```

I need to replace all element of skills array field. How this can be achieved using mongodb java driver, or other query types?

Comment: You can overwrite your array. Just use `db.colname.find({"_id": "uniqueid"}, {$set:{"skills":new array}})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use **$set** operator [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to set skills to a new value which will be an array of the new element you want to replace with.

```
 db.collectionName.update(
   { _id: 'uniqueid' },
   { $set:
      {            
        skills: [{'new elements'}]
      }
   }
)
```

if you want to remove all elements set the skills to an empty array {skills: []}

if you want to remove a certain elements based on a value use $pull operator [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)